# model did not return a loss / BertForQuestionAnswering.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have this data:

`intents.json`:

```
{"version": "0.1.0",
    "data":
 [
        {"id": "hi", 
        "question": ["hi", "how are you"],
        "answers": ["hi!", "how can i help you?"],
        "context": ""
        },
        
        {"id": "bye", 
        "question": ["Bye", "good bye", "see you"],
        "answers": ["see you later", "have a nice day", "bye", "thanks for visiting"],
        "context": ""
        },

        {"id": "weather", 
        "question": ["how is the weather", "weather forecast", "weather"],
        "answers": ["weather is good", "we have 25 degrees"],
        "context": ""
        }

    ]
}
```

and I am trying to build a question answer bot.

I am using this code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
import datasets
from transformers import AutoTokenizer,  AutoModel, TrainingArguments,\
    Trainer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, DefaultDataCollator, \
        DataCollatorForLanguageModeling

MAX_LENGTH = 128

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

def preprocess_func(x): 
    return tokenizer(x["id"],
                     padding='max_length',
                     truncation=True,
                     max_length=MAX_LENGTH)

train = load_dataset('json', data_files='intents.json', field='data', split='train[:80%]')
test = load_dataset('json', data_files='intents.json', field='data', split='train[80%:]')
 
data = datasets.DatasetDict({"train":train, "test": test})

tokenized = data.map(preprocess_func, batched=True)

#data_collator = DefaultDataCollator()
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=True
)

device = "cpu"
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = model.to(device)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
  output_dir="./results",
  evaluation_strategy="epoch",
  learning_rate=2e-5,
  per_device_train_batch_size=2,
  num_train_epochs=2,
  weight_decay=0.01,
)

trainer = Trainer(
  model=model,
  args=training_args,
  train_dataset=tokenized["train"],
  tokenizer=tokenizer,
  data_collator=data_collator,
)

trainer.train()
```

and I am receiving:

`BertForQuestionAnswering.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'`

but I don't have any labels in the data:

```
tokenized

DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['context', 'id', 'question', 'answers', 'input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask'],
        num_rows: 2
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['context', 'id', 'question', 'answers', 'input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask'],
        num_rows: 1
    })
})
```

If I use :

`DefaultDataCollator()` instead of `DataCollatorForLanguageModeling`, I receive:

`The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: start_logits,end_logits`

I am not sure if the `preprocess_func` needs more things to do.

Like, for example [here](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/lets-build-an-ai-powered-question-answering-system-with-huggingface-transformers-2622d8de18e9)

```
def preprocess_function(examples):
    questions = [q.strip() for q in examples["question"]]
    inputs = tokenizer(
        questions,
        examples["context"],
        max_length=512,
        truncation="only_second",
        return_offsets_mapping=True,
        padding="max_length",
    )

    offset_mapping = inputs.pop("offset_mapping")
    answers = examples["answers"]
    start_positions = []
    end_positions = []

    for i, offset in enumerate(offset_mapping):
        answer = answers[i]
        start_char = answer["answer_start"][0]
        end_char = answer["answer_start"][0] + len(answer["text"][0])
        sequence_ids = inputs.sequence_ids(i)

        # Find the start and end of the context
        idx = 0
        while sequence_ids[idx] != 1:
            idx += 1
        context_start = idx
        while sequence_ids[idx] == 1:
            idx += 1
        context_end = idx - 1

        # If the answer is not fully inside the context, label it (0, 0)
        if offset[context_start][0] > end_char or offset[context_end][1] < start_char:
            start_positions.append(0)
            end_positions.append(0)
        else:
            # Otherwise it's the start and end token positions
            idx = context_start
            while idx <= context_end and offset[idx][0] <= start_char:
                idx += 1
            start_positions.append(idx - 1)

            idx = context_end
            while idx >= context_start and offset[idx][1] >= end_char:
                idx -= 1
            end_positions.append(idx + 1)

    inputs["start_positions"] = start_positions
    inputs["end_positions"] = end_positions
    return inputs
```

Answer (score 2):

As is so often the case, **the problem starts with the data**. In your case there is an issue with how you format your data.

I reverse engineered the squad data that has been used in your example. I then dumped it to a .json file - you can do that as follows to have a look yourself:

```
from datasets import load_dataset                   

squad = load_dataset("squad", split="train")        
squad.to_json("squad.json")
```

and had a look on how the data needs to be set up.

```
{
    "id":"0",
    "title":"Weather",
    "context":"The weather is good today, we have 25 degrees.",
    "question":"How is the weather?",
    "answers":{"text":["The weather is good today","good","we have 25 degrees"],
    "answer_start":[0,16,28]}
}
```

**The things that need to be appreciated**

1. You will definitely need a context, minimum viable context is the answer itself.
2. Accordingly you will need an answer_start value for each of your answers, in the minimum viable version this will default to [0].
3. I also did not come across multiple questions in a single entry, as you tried in your data. There is a semantic reasoning why the data structure expects question (singular) and answers (plural).

To get you kick started in no time. This is a minimal viable example for your intents.json, obviously you need to add your own data to that.

```
{"version": "0.1.0",
 "data": [{
    "id":"0",
    "title":"Weather",
    "context":"The weather is good today, we have 25 degrees.",
    "question":"How is the weather?",
    "answers":{"text":["The weather is good today","good","we have 25 degrees"],
    "answer_start":[0,16,28]}
},
{
    "id":"1",
    "title":"Weather",
    "context":"The weather is good today, we have 25 degrees.",
    "question":"Weather forecast",
    "answers":{"text":["The weather is good today","good","we have 25 degrees"],
    "answer_start":[0,16,28]}
}]
}
```

This **data can be loaded** as such:

```
from datasets import load_dataset

data_files = {"train": "intents.json"}
train = load_dataset("json", data_files=data_files, field='data', split="train[:50%]")

data_files = {"train": "intents.json"}
test = load_dataset("json", data_files=data_files, field='data', split="train[50%:]")

data = datasets.DatasetDict({"train": train, "validation": test})
```

The preprocess_function is exactly as the one you did propose from the example. I have been using the DefaultDataCollator() for the **training pipeline**.

To make things easy, this is how everything below loading and preprocessing looks like. I also made sure to try with the model you wanted to use, and I did not have an issue with that.

```
tokenized_squad = data.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)

from transformers import DefaultDataCollator
data_collator = DefaultDataCollator()

from transformers import AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, TrainingArguments, Trainer
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

training_args = TrainingArguments(
 output_dir="./results",
 evaluation_strategy="epoch",
 learning_rate=2e-5,
 per_device_train_batch_size=2,
 per_device_eval_batch_size=2,
 num_train_epochs=2,
 weight_decay=0.01,
)

trainer = Trainer(
 model=model,
 args=training_args,
 train_dataset=tokenized_squad["train"],
 eval_dataset=tokenized_squad["validation"],
 tokenizer=tokenizer,
 data_collator=data_collator,
)
trainer.train()
```

**Training succeeds** after the specified two epochs, as such:

```
> {'eval_loss': 5.697275161743164, 'eval_runtime': 1.8384,
> 'eval_samples_per_second': 0.544, 'eval_steps_per_second': 0.544,
> 'epoch': 2.0} {'train_runtime': 12.7593, 'train_samples_per_second':
> 0.157, 'train_steps_per_second': 0.157, 'train_loss': 6.120669364929199, 'epoch': 2.0}
```

I enjoyed going down your rabbit hole, I hope you appreciate the answer and can now train your model.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the solution. The thing is that I want multiple values in the `question` field. So, the user must be able to ask a range of questions and receive one answer (or more). And for this kind of setup I don't think `context` is necessary.  I mean, I don't have a text from which I have to retrieve the answer, rather a set of questions the user does and find the appropriate answer.

Comment: Sure in my opinion this is a question of framing your problem and make it fit with the data structure given. As described in my answer I would use your answer as the context if you have no other context, the answer_start can then default to 0. If you have multiple answers that can then be reflected as multiple entries in your data, or concatenate all answers into a single context. The same applies to multiple questions - this definitely needs to be reflected as multiple entries in your dataset. The entries in your json are then generated as combinations of questions and answers.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Because that's what I am struggling for. And what about `answer_start` values? Just start from 0 and increment by what number?

Comment: An example on how to add an entry for different questions is in my answer above. The answer_start values just go from 0 and are incremented by the character length of the answer in case of concatenating. Or just always from 0 in case of separating into multiple entries.

Comment: Your answer works if you have one context and one question. It can't work if you have multiple questions and no context, like the original post.

Comment: Maybe one more thing, the architecture you are using is an " extractive question answering" one. The more you are describing what you want to achieve, what you actually need is a Closed-book QA architecture (read this blogpost: https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2020-10-29-odqa/#closed-book-qa-generative-language-model) there is also work on hugging face to fine-tune for example the T5 model (check it out here: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/t5-for-closed-book-qa/11475/2) .. that however would be an entire different undertaking, and should be discussed in a new question if you feel the need.

Comment: It can work if you have multiple questions and default your context to your answer. As said this just needs to be framed as multiple entries on which you then again can train as desired. However, notice that you will have to hand over a "text" (context) during inference, or you need to move to an entire different model architecture - as detailed in my last comment.